# "Your report ...is being reviewed"

Tags: tense

Could you please explain this sentence:

> Your report...is being reviewed.

1. Is this correct sentence?
2. What does *being* mean here, continues action?
3. Which tense is used?

Full Sentence

> Your report has been received and is being reviewed by our support staff.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Could you please note where you saw this text? It's not a particularly normal usage...

Comment: @Adam "Your report is being reviewed" is a perfectly fine sentence... provided "your" is included, which you've done. seems fine now, which is why I deleted my comment.

Comment: 1.yes, 2 means your report is under referee and examination ,3 it is passive form of  the present participle. ( I think)

Comment: In my experience, it means someone acknowledged that you submitted something, and they're going to ignore it for a few weeks. Just my experience...

Comment: The tense is passive, present tense continuous form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Your report has been received and is being reviewed by our support staff.

This is a perfectly normal "message received" notice that I see on a regular basis. There's nothing wrong with it, grammatically, that I can think of.

It's the combination of two statements:

> Your report has been received by our support staff.
>   Your report is being reviewed by our support staff.

The first sentence is telling you that your message to their support staff has been received. They got the email.

The second sentence is telling you that the current step in the process is for them to look over (review) what you've sent and investigate what you've told them. We use "being reviewed" to show that it's a current and ongoing action.

"Is being reviewed" is the [present continuous passive tense](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-m_vmwct_3.htm) (AKA present progressive passive).

Realistically, the report is not likely *actually* "being reviewed" at the exact moment you're reading the message so it could be argued that it would be preferable to be more honest and say

> Your report **will be** reviewed by our support staff.

Why they make this choice, I'm not sure... likely because it makes the reader feel like their report is "in process" rather than sitting in a queue, waiting for attention.

Comment: As you said, they use that as matter of the fact that the review is a process and takes time. However, it is very common in journal papers. I am not sure about a report.

Comment: @Cardinal I'm guessing the sentence is talking about something like a "bug report" or "error report", in which case it's extremely common to use this form. Some of those bugs take seconds to investigate and some take weeks... depends on the bug.

Comment: The portion in your answer that I find questionable is classifying "is being" as "present continuous *passive* tense".  It *isn't passive **until*** you add a *past participle*.  Example of *not* passive: "he *is being* silly, don't take him seriously!"

Comment: @VictorBazarov and "reviewed" isn't past tense?

Comment: Read the sentence as you wrote it: {"Is being" is the present continuous passive tense (AKA present progressive passive).}  That's just not true. You forgot to mention the past participle here.  Get it?

Comment: @VictorBazarov the op was specifically asking about being, so I chose to frame it that way... In fact, my original version only said "present continuous"... But you can't see that because the edit was too soon after the original submission.

Comment: And it *is* Present Continuous.  There used to be no such thing as "Passive Tense".  It used to be "passive *voice*"...  Times change.

Answer (score 4):

This is the *progressive*<sup>†</sup> *passive construction*.

> ***is being*** (= a form of *BE* + *present participle*) is the progressive piece, and
>   and ***being reviewed*** (- a form of *BE* + *past participle*) is the passive piece.

Complex verb constructions are always laid out with the auxiliaries in the same order—Modal, Perfect, Progressive, Passive, Lexical verb—with each verb taking the form required by the previous auxiliary:

[image: Pcon4]

Your example uses pieces 3), 4) and 5).

---

<sup>†</sup> 'Progressive' is also called 'continuous'. I use 'progressive' because I like all those Ps.

Comment: HA HA... I saw your answer and it was different than mine and I got worried because you know so much more than I do about grammar structures.

Comment: @Catija Yours is considerably more useful than mine on the meaning side. That's why we need multiple answers!

Answer (score -1):

Lexically/semantically rather than syntactically like some of the other answers here...

It is to mean:

> Your report is under review.

Or

> Your report has been received by our penguins and review (by the penguins) is underway.

To German 3 year old, everything zu machen.

English often uses quixotic verb conjugations as opposed to prepositional logic. The latter must be difficult to think of on the fly. There is some folk wisdom concerning the use of verb phrases like "think of," that they shouldn't end sentences or clauses or somesuch.

Comment: I'm not sure what the last two paragraphs have to do with the question.